# Page number alignment in ToC with long title and section number

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, alignment, page-numbers

I can not insert the screenshot, but here is a preview (mockup?) of what I get:

[Wrong page number alignment in ToC with long title and section number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clAkg.png)

[Link to similar issue](http://shrani.si/f/2P/HR/3tCOWsFC/toc-align.jpg)

---

Table of Content

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...............................1

   1.1 Duis dapibus posuere odio et viverra. Integer augue

   ```
      1
   ```

Now the text...

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in diam turpis.

   1.1 Duis dapibus posuere odio et viverra. Integer augue turpis, pulvinar vel turpis non, conse

---

The page number alignment for the second level title is misplaced to the left under the title.

This is because of the tab added to the table of contents to create a space between the section number and the title.

The only solution I have found is to add periods to get past the tab mark and make them white. Then they do not appear in the body of the text, but appear in the table of contents.
Is there a cleaner solution?

ps : My university requires that the ToC be generated without manual(local) change!

Answer (score 0):

After so much attention and comment, I take things in my hands!

1. As I said above, add periods to the title in the text to get past the tab mark and make them white. Ugly but it's working.
2. Change the character to space after the number in the multi-level list style (numbering). Sometimes not very pretty, but ok.
3. Shrink or enlarge the title.
4. Add the field code \x to the ToC code and add in the title a hidden line break, be sure to remove also the \h field in the ToC code.

Any other trick?